# Locking the screen orientation per screen in Flutter does not work on iPad

Tags: flutter, ipad, screen-orientation

I am developing an app that locks the screen orientation to portrait or landscape depending on which screen it is. I.e. I have a setup flow that uses portrait mode but when done and starting the "app" I switch over to landscape mode.

Anyhow the per screen locking code (that is recommended when googling) works fine on my iPhone but on my iPad it does not work.

On the iPad the screen rotates and turns black.

The code that locks the setup screen:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
  }
```

And yes i have done

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Answer (score 3):

I've finally fixed it by manually editing the Info.plist file.

Open it with a text editor and change the supported orientation values you find with those:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

The first block is for iPhone, the second one is for iPad (this will block multitasking)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the orientation for ios devices is set to *Portrait*. To enable other orientations, go to the `{your_project}/ios/runner/` directory and open the `info.plist` file and add the following line

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key> //This line indicates the preferred orientations for ios devices
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>  //This Line is there by default
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string> //Add this line to enable landscape orientation
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>  //This line indicates the preferred orientations for ipados devices
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

after saving the `info.plist` file rebuild your flutter project and it should work fine.